# Changing DataTemplates at Runtime

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I'd like to be able to swap out data templates at runtime, but without the

```
FindResource("fdds") as DataTemplate
```

Type of code I've seen a lot.  I'd like to be able to just bind the template to look for the resource according to a property in my ViewModel.  Conceptually I'd like to be able to do this, but the compiler obviously doesn't like it:

```
 ... ItemTemplate="{StaticResource {Binding Path=VMTemplate}}">
```

And then other commands would change the value of VMTemplate in the ViewModel. Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StaticResource extension is an immediate lookup when the XAML is parsed which means the Resource must be present at the start of the app.  In order to set a template dynamically you will have to do something similar to the way your first line looks.

A possibility I have seen would be to make the DataTemplate have a custom control that extends `ContentControl` that has multiple DataTemplate properties that would then be able to select different templates based on a bound value from your View Model.